# Lack of preprocessor problems

Tags: java, android, preprocessor

I am writing an Android application in which we want portions of the code to be split out so we can give them out as libraries with which customers can build their own apps that hit our API. The problem is that we need some of that same code to do certain things differently for us, as we build our own in house apps. I know Java doesn't have a preprocessor. So is there any way for me to compile 1 set of code on one kind of compile, and another set of code on a different kind of compile, without actually having to maintain 2 separate sets of code that do basically the same thing?

Comment: You can use product flavors to have replacements for the classes that differ between the two scenarios, though IIRC product flavor-based libraries are somewhat annoying to use.

Comment: That's an interesting thought. I might give that a shot.

Comment: You might look at how the sources of Android itself (AOSP) build into both a complete internal version installed on devices, and a stripped-down SDK missing elements not intended to be externally linked.

Comment: @CommonsWare Your answer actually led to another question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729260/dependency-configurations