# Dependency configurations

Tags: android, configuration, dependencies

I know that if I make a library that uses product flavors, then when I use that library in an application, I can do this in a gradle:

```
dependencies {
    flavor1Compile(path: '{path}', configuration: 'flavor1Config')
    flavor2Compile(path: '{path}', configuration: 'flavor2Config')
}
```

I also know that I can do this:

```
dependencies {
    debugCompile(path: '{path}', configuration: 'debugConfig')
    releaseCompile(path: '{path}', configuration: 'releaseConfig')
}
```

What I want to do is essentially this:

```
dependencies {
    flavor1DebugCompile(path: '{path}', configuration: 'flavor1DebugConfig')
    flavor1ReleaseCompile(path: '{path}', configuration: 'flavor1ReleaseConfig')
    flavor2DebugCompile(path: '{path}', configuration: 'flavor2DebugConfig')
    flavor2ReleaseCompile(path: '{path}', configuration: 'flavor2ReleaseConfig')
}
```

But that code produces this:

> Error:(30, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'flavor1DebugCompile()'
>   Possible causes:
>
> The project 'android' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>   Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
>   Apply Gradle plugin

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What exactly are your symptoms? IOW, what does "doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 1):

There is [an open bug on the Android issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=162285) to support this.

As of right now, you can accomplish this by declaring a configuration like so for each combination you want to use:

```
configurations {
  flavor1DebugCompile
} 

dependencies {
  flavor1DebugCompile(path: '{path}', configuration: 'flavor1DebugConfig')
}
```

Comment: Well, that got me past the error I described, but it leads to another problem.  See I have 1 core library where I'm using the productFlavors, then other libraries that all use that core one, and if I try to use those other libraries using this method, I don't get that error anymore, but I'm also unable to access the packages inside them.

Comment: [u2020](https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020) is a good example of a project that uses this. The "internalDebugCompile" configuration uses this pattern.

Comment: That doesn't address the new problem. The new problem is that I can't access the packages of a library that includes a library that uses product flavors.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. The problem is that the build system doesn't support specifying a product flavor for a library. If you need to access classes in one flavor of a library, but the library was built using a different flavor, you won't be able to access those classes. The library either needs to be published separately using the other flavor, or you need to use the library as a module project and not a dependency.